# Coded UI - How to launch website in IE InPrivate Browsing mode?

Tags: automated-testing, c#, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to launch my website by default in IE InPrivate mode so I can get rid of tons of code to handle multiple scenarios (listed below) script may counter during execution. My goal is to run browser in no previous history and etc..

- Google account has valid session and have signed up with our app
- Google account has valid session but not used to signup with our web app.
- Google account has no session but have remembered previously entered Email/User.
- Google account has no session but have remembered previously entered Email/User and Password.
- Google account is never signed in or used with our app (most simple case)

Note: Following built-in methods in BrowserWindow class aren't much helpful.

```cs
BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("www.mysite.com");
BrowserWindow.ClearCache();
BrowserWindow.ClearCookies();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can run it using**

```
BrowserWindow.Launch("http://www.google.com/", "-private");
```

Official information is available [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/888978/Starting-an-InPrivate-instance-of-Internet-Explore).